# Elm, Switzerland - Suvorov monument and Glarus thrust

Tags: guides, switzerland, mountains

I'm searching for any tours in this municipality from Bern.
I'm going to visit [Elm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elm,_Switzerland) to view the Suvorov monument there:

[image: Suvorov monument]

and the [Glarus thrust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glarus_thrust):

[image: Glarus thrust]

Do you know any variants? I heard there is a ski resort I can visit, and that's all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suworow monument shown in your first picture is on [Gotthard-Pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotthard_Pass). There are lot of excellent tours on [Switzerland Tourism](http://www.myswitzerland.com/en/home.html) described.

The second picture show the "Martinsloch" through which the sun shines on church tower of Elm. This happens only twice a year (around march, 12th and september, 30th).

Comment: Is there any tours from Elm to Gotthard-Pass?

Comment: Guided tours? Well you will have to contact [elm tourism](http://www.elm.ch). By public transport check [www.sbb.ch](http://www.sbb.ch).

Comment: It is not so easy to get to the Martinsloch. As you can see here (http://www.hikr.org/dir/Martinsloch_8100/), it is at least T4.